# iPhone: "Finger Print Scanner" avaliable as an API?

Tags: iphone, ios, touch-id

Is "Finger Print Recognition" in IOS available or will be available in future as an API? I want to use it from my own app for instance to authorize users to the app itself, or to login to certain webpages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Apple stated the fingerprint scanner is only available to built in apps, not to any 3rd party apps

Answer (score 3):

There was no new announced Security API announced for the TouchID sensor. I'm guessing we would have to wait until WWDC 2014 (hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

No it is not available in iOS 7.0 GM. When Apple introduces new technology they usually keep it private for a release or two while it gets fine tuned.

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed by Phil Schiller, there is no API as of right now, but he did not want to comment on whether there will be or not in the future.